# Can protractor be run from two different logins/users on same host?

Tags: protractor

I have few CI machines to un protractor jobs, as test case count increased, job completion time also followed the same path.
Now instead of having more machines, I am thinking of adding new users to same VMs, but before that I want to ensure if protractor process can be invoked from two different machines or not.
Also, would Chrome and Firefox work simultaneously on two different user accounts or this is not supported.

Comment: Have you tried sharding your tests to improve execution time? `shardTestFiles` and `maxInstances` may help you not have to run tests with 2 different users. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/0cd156d6829f23f93403d865b7fdb7eab4f45446/lib/config.ts#L282

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in a more generic way, Yes, you can distribute your Protractor execution processes on multiple machines or multiple Users on same machine. But I have a better suggestion to adapt to the latest trends :)

Establish a Selenium Grid using docker containers. You can have a combination like below

- docker container 1: - hosts the Hub - May be this image -
  [selenium/hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/hub/)
- docker container 2(can be multiple): - hosts the chrome node -
  [selenium/node-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/)
- docker container 3(can be multiple): - hosts the firefox node -
  [selenium/node-firefox](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/)

Protractor process will run only on the master machine and actual execution will happen on the docker containers. This set of docker containers can be located on an external machine outside the one that hosts Jenkins

Comment: Thanks for this, It looks promising. I will give it a try and report back soon.